# How can I fade out tab content div before loading the next?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, slideshow

I'm using tabs to allow site visitors to navigate content in part of a web page.

It all works wonderfully, with one teeny-tiny minor issue—from what I can tell, clicking on a button jumps to the new content and fades it in.

Not a problem for some, but I'd like the original content to fade out before the new content is faded in because I'm fancy (and picky) like that.

Presumably one way this can be achieved by delaying the loading of the new content (which seems to be created by changing the display from "none" to "block") and allowing a button click to first affect (i.e. fade out) the existing content... Just brainstorming here.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I'm using (from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp):

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 2s;
  animation: fadeEffect 2s;
}

/* Fade in tabs */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<h3>Fade in Tabs</h3>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this? Is this what you wanted?

Here is working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Kretiss/1c5zeynx/6/

### Here is your CSS:

```
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

### Here is your HTML

```
  <h3>Fade in Tabs</h3>

  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" data-place="London">London</button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-place="Paris">Paris</button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-place="Tokyo">Tokyo</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tabcontent" data-place="London">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="tabcontent" data-place="Paris">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="tabcontent" data-place="Tokyo">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  let switching = true;
  const defaultOpen = "London";

  $("button[data-place=" + defaultOpen + "]").addClass("active");
  $("div[data-place=" + defaultOpen + "]").fadeIn(250, function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    switching = false;
  });


  $(".tablinks").click(function(){
    const switchToAttr = $(this).attr("data-place");
    const switchTo = $("div[data-place=" + switchToAttr + "]");
    const prevDiv = $("div.active");

    if(!switching && switchToAttr != prevDiv.attr("data-place")){
      switching = true;

      $("button.active").removeClass("active");
      prevDiv.removeClass("active");

      $(this).addClass("active");
      switchTo.addClass("active");

      prevDiv.fadeOut(250, function(){
        switchTo.fadeIn(250);
        switching = false;
      });

    }

  });

});

</script>
```

When page is loaded, JQuery fadeIn tab London. After that you can click on any tab you want and it first checks, if last switch is complete and if tab is different then what is now active. Then it simply just switch classes and do fadeIn effect, which is fired after fadeOut of previous div is complete, as you wanted.

Comment: Wow, excellent! Thanks very much.  

Yes, this is essentially what I want to do, but with two issues:  

1) Is it possible to do this with just JS?  
2) Is it possible use an id like "defaultOpen" rather than "London"? This'll allow me to choose to have content loaded with a more logical title. In your fiddle when I changed the two instances of the word "London" to "defaultOpen" it worked for a few button clicks, then the content stopped being loaded. Here's a fiddle showing what I mean (I also increased the fade times so the effect is more apparent): https://jsfiddle.net/badL54r0/

Comment: I will look at it in the morning or after lunch :)

Comment: I updated my answer, so now you have `const defaultOpen = "London";`. Hopefully it'll suit what you wanted at least a little. But I didn't do it in JS, because it's easier for me in JQuery and I don't have that much experience with ordinary JS, maybe someone else could add it. But I don't know why not to use JQuery, its relatively easy to understand and easy to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but your updated code seems to be identical to the code I posted in my previous comment and creating the identical problem of the content not loading.  I also want to use JS because that's what the original code is written in. I want to add to the existing code rather than have to use new code.

Comment: You can change only `const defaultOpen = "London";` to for example `const defaultOpen = "Paris";` in JQuery, but dont change anything in html.